# Compilation of main tex file from a chapter file with AucTeX

Tags: compiling, auctex

I have a main LaTeX file that has multiple chapter files included using `\input` command.
For compiling them in emacs/auctex, I have to open main LaTeX and `^C^C`.

How can I compile the main LaTeX from a chapter file?

### ADDED

I don't know exactly what happened, but I had to use `^C _` to specify the master file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199463/emacs-auctex-run-command-on-file-that-is-not-currently-open

Comment: The reason it didn't work when you did it manually is that the variable only takes effect when you reopen the buffer. You could save the file and then do `revert-buffer` to reload it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add at the end of each chapter file

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "THEMAINFILE"
%%% End:
```

to point AUCTeX to the main file. Furthermore, ([quoting the AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html))

> if you often use `\include` or `\input`, you should make AUCTeX aware of the multi-file document structure.  You can do this by inserting `(setq-default TeX-master nil)` into your init file.  Each time you open a new file, AUCTeX will then
>   ask you for a master file.

Or, if you usually use the same master filename

> You should always set this variable to the name of the top level document. If you always use the same name for your top level documents, you can set TeX-master in your `.emacs` file.
>
> `(setq-default TeX-master "master") ; All master files called "master".`

Comment: Could it be applied for the if the chapter linked as `\subfile{cost}`?

Comment: On my system I had to save the file and reopen it before this worked. Took me an embarrassing amount of time to figure that out!